# bash function to create a "content-hash" of a specific git commit

Tags: bash, git, hash

**NO, I'M NOT TALKING ABOUT THE GIT COMMIT HASH!!!** :)

It's easy to end up with 2 git commits which have identical codebases, but different commit hashes.

Perhaps you interactively rebased to re-order commits. Or you have tried out both merging an rebasing a branch. Or you have reverted the most recent commit because it broke the build. Whatever the cause, you have 2 commits with different commit hashes / git histories, but identical contents in terms of the codebase being tracked. I will refer to such commits as "content-identical".

I often want to keep track of which commits are "content-identical", so I need to compare two commits to check for differences. If both those commits exist at the same time, that's easy enough - just diff them, and observe an empty set.

But if I'm doing a whole bunch of interactive rebasing then I often want to check "is this commit "content-identical" to the commit I had half an hour ago before I mucked around with it's ancestors. Or "I know that the codebase was fully green at  half an hour ago ... so if it's content-identical to  now, then I don't need to re-run the tests *(Yes, I know, a good test suite would be quick enough, that running the tests isn't an imposition. ... I don't have a good test suite)*. But the previous version of the commit isn't easily accessible. I could keep "XXX_old" branches lying around all the time, pointing to the pre-rebased version of the commits, so that I can still see them. Or I could faff around in `git reflog`. ... But really what I want to do is to create a content-hash, that I can use to identify which commits I've already fully tested.

How would I go about writing a bash script to generate that sort of "content-hash" of the code-base represented by a git commit?

Requirements:

- Does vary when git-tracked files change (incl. new files being added or removed from git)
- Doesn't vary based on the current git hash / git history.
- Doesn't vary based on untracked files (compiled binaries, etc)
- Standard hash properties - collisions are statistically improbable, albeit mathematically guaranteed to exist somewhere.
- Written exclusively in `bash` (no python, etc.)

Preferrably also:

- Doesn't require checking out the target commit - can be pointed at any arbitrary commit in the git history.

Comment: Look at how Gerrit marks commits (to track amended/rebased commits) in `commit-msg` hook.

Comment: If I get that right, then your original issue is that delete most branches and commits from your git repository to safe space (and maybe efficiency). Otherwise you could simply re-checkout the "old" branch / commit and again do a diff to compare both commits. 
Instead of trying to invent new tools - why don't you simply keep those branches / commits around? They usually don't really hurt, git is pretty good when it comes to long term storage efficiency. And in general I would _alway_ recommend not to rely on just a local git repository, but to have an upstream repo in some other location.

Comment: @arkascha if you don't store something specific to the *state*, then you'd have to diff the current commit against every previous one in order to know if the current one has already been tested. By storing a separate "state" representation per commit, you only need to test if the current state exists anywhere in the saved list.

Comment: @TTT Sounds massively overengineered to me, considering that you usually _know_ what you are doing when reverting a git commit.

Comment: @arkascha the reverting case is a simple one to trivially demonstrate the existence of multiple commits that are content-identical whilst having different commit hashes/histories. In reality what I'm actually going to be using this for is for tracking which commits are known to be good, clean codebases (compiles, and passes all tests) whilst doing extensive interactive rebases.)

Comment: I understood all that, it is not rocket science. I said it is over engineered. But that is just my opinion. You certainly do know better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't need to "create" a hash of the tracked files; Git already does this automatically. All you need to do is ask Git to show you what it is.

After you have created a commit, you can run the following command to achieve your goal:

```
git rev-parse @^{tree}
# or
git rev-parse @:
```

Note that `@` is just shorthand for `HEAD` and works without escaping in most shells, including Bash. The first part of that command: `git rev-parse @` will print out the current commit ID, however, `rev-parse` can also print out the hash of the file system tree for a provided [type](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtlttypegtemegemv0998commitem) or [path](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememmasterREADMEem). In your case you only need the root so you can use either `^{tree}` or `:`.

It's easy to verify this works by comparing different commits that have the same state, and validating that the provided tree-hash is identical.

As for this requirement:

> Doesn't require checking out the target commit - can be pointed at any arbitrary commit in the git history.

You can change `@` to be any commit ID you wish, to build up the history with a one-time pass of already tested states. From then on you can use `@` after each new commit.

Comment: Just `@:`, that's always the root tree hash., No need to ask for the `./` part, the current working directory's hash, at all? Or for something that short the equivalent `@^{tree}` might be clearer.

Comment: @jthill thanks. I incorporated your comment into the answer.

Comment: I'd like to add that "content-identical" is a bit ambiguous and OP perhaps isn't aware of it. The input that generates the tree hash contains the information of the executable bit of a file. For a tracked file, it's quite common that we have two versions whose contents are exactly the same. But one is executable and the other is not. This tiny difference leads to two hash values.

Comment: @ElpieKay good point. From a "has this commit been tested yet" POV, I think I'd prefer it changing anyway if that bit is modified, since it's likely to be intentional.

Comment: @ElpieKay what do you mean by the "executable bit of a file"?

Comment: Oh, do you mean permissions flags? Yeah, I would definitely say that if the permissions have changed then that is a (subtly!) different file (and thus codebase). If I've changed that during rebasing, then I'd want to know about it and re-test it. (and as TTT says, it's highly likely to have been intentional)